Gravity not being applied to the body
I am trying to set up a gravity system in a project I am working in. But for some reason it is not being applied. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?
For context, I am using Box2D 3.0.0 and SDL2 I have the important code below. The variable _props is in charge of drawing the world.
Creating the world:
entitymanager::entitymanager() {
  auto worldDef = b2DefaultWorldDef();
  worldDef.gravity = {0.0f, -10.0f};

  _world = b2CreateWorld(&worldDef);
}

Create a body:
 auto bodyDef = b2DefaultBodyDef();
  bodyDef.position = {.0f, .0f};
  bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

  const auto body = b2CreateBody(_world, &bodyDef);

  b2Polygon shape = b2MakeBox(
      (width - margin.left - margin.right) * .5f,
      (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) * .5f
  );

  b2ShapeDef shapeDef = b2DefaultShapeDef();
  shapeDef.density = p.value("density", 1.f);
  shapeDef.friction = 0.3f;
  b2CreatePolygonShape(body, &shapeDef, &shape);

On every game loop I do this:
void entitymanager::update(float_t delta) {
  b2World_Step(_world, delta, 4);

  for (const auto &entity : _entities) {
    entity->update();
  }
}

Where entity::update is:
const auto position = b2Body_GetPosition(_props.body);
_props.position.set(
  static_cast<int32_t>(std::round(position.x)),
  static_cast<int32_t>(std::round(position.y))
);

_props.angle = b2Rot_GetAngle(b2Body_GetRotation(_props.body));


I might be wrong, but the tag wiki says "Box2D is a free open source 2-dimensional physics simulator engine written in C++ by Erin Catto and published under the zlib license". Anyhow, none of the code you show is c code

A [mre] would help..

This is a classic mistake regarding rounding and casting. Rounding a position in space or casting a fraction to an integer, results in the integer discarding any fractional information.
What happens is that your delta is too small for the position to significantly update to a new integer position. So, when you round it, it will round to the nearest integer. In this case back to its original position.
Try to avoid rounding when it comes to position. You could also increase the gravity to see when it begins to move.
Edit:
The solution has come to light, though rounding a position can have this effect as well.

I tried to improve the gravity, removed the roundings and nothing worked.
My delta is something between 17 and 16

Yes but you should pass this delta in the update function and also do the multiplication.

@AmparoWalter, look carefully, the position variable of the _props class has nothing to do with calculating the next step. The problem here is not rounding at all.

There were two problems, my delta was wrong (something between 16 and 17), because of that, on first frame the sprites were out of screen.
The second problem was the size, it was too large. For now I have fixed to 1.0f w & h and it worked perfectly

Glad you found the error
